# How to get Windows Explorer's selected file from within Excel VBA? What is de VBA code needed to do this?

Tags: excel, vba

I want to capture the name of the file already selected (with the checkbox selected) in a Windows Explorer open window using Excel VBA code. How do I do This? What is the code needed?

Answer (score 1):

An alternate method: You can use a version of getsaveasname, or getopenfilename to open a dialog box that will prompt you to select a file assign the result to a variable and then you can do what you need to with it. You don't have to save or open the file, but those two inputboxes each have different settings.

`nameYouWant = application.GetSaveAsName`

I'm not sure how to do what you want to do, but it would take some really complex code in my estimation.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/getfilename-method-visual-basic-for-applications

https://wellsr.com/vba/2018/excel/get-filename-with-vba-getopenfilename/

In order to get excel to look outside itself to a different program is difficult. It means you would need to reference another library. If you are new to VBA, I wouldn't try to tackle it, but change your process if you can.

To give you a taste, here are some subroutines that are on the track of what you are asking for:
https://wellsr.com/vba/2016/excel/open-folder-using-vba-and-show-if-already-open/
http://vbadud.blogspot.com/2009/01/how-to-windows-explorer-using-vba.html

Comment: Thank you Palinnalip! Let me explain what I need to do but be aware that I new in VBA. I want to select a "pdf" file in a Windows Explorer's window already open and "then", using VBA code within a Excel sheet, get the name of that selected file and use it. I need to use Windows Explorer to view the content and select a specific file among others.

Comment: What I am trying to do is: "first" select one file in a Windows Explorer window and "then" toggle to excel app and get its name with VBA code. Is this possible?

Comment: Thanks again Palinnalip! But I am very sure about what I want and "is not" to open a file from within Excel. Like I said, I want to capture the file name of a file "already selected" in an already open explorer's window. I dont want any kind of walkarounds and no matter how dificult it would be, once I have the precise directions. Thanks once more and if you can help-me I would be even more thankfull. Regards.